# NestJS Enumerate loaded modules and invoke a method of the service if service extends specific class

Tags: module, nestjs

I am building monitoring module for NestJS project that enumerates loaded modules and calls `getStatus()` method for modules that extends custom `BaseService` class (which has default implementation of `getStatus()`). I do not know what modules will be loaded, so I can not inject them in constructor() like we usually do it.
It makes no sense to create a new instance of the service, because I want to query status of running instance.

I have successfully managed to enumerate modules like so:

```js
@Injectable()
export class StatusService extends BaseService {
    constructor(readonly modulesContainer: ModulesContainer) {
        super();
    }

    onModuleInit() {
        const modules = [...this.modulesContainer.values()];
        for (const module of modules) {
            // get instance of service and call getStatus()
        }
    }
```

But I am struggling in finding instance of the service in `module`.

Please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do:

```js
module.providers.forEach((value) => {
    if (value.instance && typeof value.instance.getStatus === 'function') {
        const status = value.instance.getStatus();
    });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).